# xfreerdp not connect to server with different RDP port!

Tags: fedora, remote-desktop, xfreerdp, xrdp

I have changed default RDP port on server from 3389 to 1687.

Here is the command I'm trying to connect :

```
xfreerdp /u:administrator /v:177.8.130.250 /p:1687 /size:1280x700
```

But it returns this error :

```
[01:11:14:846] [23825:23826] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channel cliprdr
[01:11:14:019] [23825:23826] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.transport] - BIO_should_retry returned a system error 32: Broken pipe
[01:11:14:019] [23825:23826] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.nego] - Protocol Security Negotiation Failure
[01:11:14:019] [23825:23826] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_set_last_error ERRCONNECT_SECURITY_NEGO_CONNECT_FAILED [0x2000C]
[01:11:14:019] [23825:23826] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.connection] - Error: protocol security negotiation or connection failure
[01:11:14:019] [23825:23826] [ERROR][com.freerdp.client.x11] - Freerdp connect error exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a user of `xfreerdp`, but [doc says](https://github.com/awakecoding/FreeRDP-Manuals/blob/master/User/FreeRDP-User-Manual.markdown), that `/p:` is option for password not for port. To connect to a different port use `/port:<port>` or `/v:<host>:<port>`